# How to test a List<SelectOtion> in unittest

Tags: apex, unit-test, class, list, get

How to test a `List<SelectOtion>` in unittest. I have the following apexclass

```
    public class WebToObjAttachments {
    ..
        public List<SelectOption> CountryOptions {
        get {
                List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
            if(!urlvalue.contains('_NL')){
                options.add(new SelectOption('NL', 'Netherlands')); 
                for (Schema.PicklistEntry pe : SObjectType.Lead.fields.CountryCode.getPicklistValues()) {

                }
                options.add(new SelectOption('BE', 'Belgium')); 
                options.add(new SelectOption('FR', 'France')); 
                options.add(new SelectOption('DE', 'Germany')); 
                options.add(new SelectOption('ES', 'Spain')); 
                options.add(new SelectOption('PT', 'Portugal')); 
                options.add(new SelectOption('IT', 'Italy')); 
                options.add(new SelectOption('GB', 'United Kingdom')); 
                options.add(new SelectOption('SCOT', 'Scotland')); 
                options.add(new SelectOption('IE', 'Ireland')); 
                options.add(new SelectOption('US', 'United States')); 
            }
         return options;
} 
    set;}
    ..
    }
```

I have tried the following but get the error: public is not allowed on locals

```
private static testMethod void CountryOptionsTest()
{
    property__c prop = new property__c();
    prop.name = 'Testproperty';
    insert prop;

    Lead le=new Lead(Lastname='Unit Test', RecordType__c = 'Guest');
    insert le;
    ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.standardController(le);
    WebToObjAttachments controller = new WebToObjAttachments(sc);

    public List<SelectOption> testoptions = controller.CountryOptions ;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error: **public is not allowed on locals**:

**Reason**

That error is coming because inside the private static method you have declared public selection Option

removed public keyword from

```
    List<SelectOption> testoptions = controller.CountryOptions ;
```

Code:

```
public static testMethod void CountryOptionsTest()
 {
property__c prop = new property__c();
prop.name = 'Testproperty';
insert prop;

Lead le=new Lead(Lastname='Unit Test', RecordType__c = 'Guest');
insert le;
ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.standardController(le);
WebToObjAttachments controller = new WebToObjAttachments(sc);
List<SelectOption> testoptions = controller.CountryOptions ;}
```